# Does this sentence sound good?

Tags: meaning

Today a coworker wrote the following sentence:

> How are you think to handle this problem ?

I cannot explain why but this sentence doesn't sound good, maybe because he used a verb - think - followed by an infinitive - to handle.
Does this sentence seem natural for a english native speaker ?

Comment: You don't say whether or not the coworker is a native English speaker. If so, it smells like a brainfart to me. I imagine the coworker meant to ask "How do you think you'll handle this problem?"

Comment: No, he is not a native english speaker. J.R can you elaborate why do you think it is a brainfart ?

Comment: I don't think it's a brainfart - not if the speaker's primary language isn't English. If native speaker typed that sentence, though, I'd probably chalk it up to blending two thoughts together while typing, and not paying attention to the end result.

Comment: The sentence is so obviously ungrammatical that I have to close the question as rhetorical. @utxeee: Read up on [do-support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support), browse the corresponding [tag](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/do-support), and note how it's not called "be-support". Speaking of support, this question might have a chance on our sister site specifically for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). You can support it by committing.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more correct version would be:

> How are you thinking to handle this problem?

which is technically correct, but still poorly worded. A better choice of words would be:

> How are you planning to handle this problem?